# How do I prevent parameter sniffing in a SELECT statement that .NET is turning into an EXEC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL SELECT statement that runs very quickly in SQL Server Management Studio (5 seconds), but runs very slowly from my ASP.NET code.

I've read that this may be related to parameter sniffing. When I run the SELECT statement from SSMS, I'm using a SELECT. But when I watch SQL Profiler, my SELECT statements are executing as stored procedures with the pattern: exec sp_executesql N'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE userid = @userid',N'@userid int',@userid=2

This ASP.NET code times out after four minutes (connection string setting):

```
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE userid = @userid", objCS);
SqlDataReader reader;
objCommand = new SqlCommand("", objCS);
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objCommand.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
SqlDataReader reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

//times out on objCommand.ExecuteReader();

This code executes in SQL Server Management Studio in 5 seconds:

```
DECLARE @userid AS Int = 2
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE userid = @userid
```

Returns 60000+ rows in 5 seconds.

How can I make the ASP.NET code execute as a SELECT statement instead of a stored procedure, while preserving the security value of parameterized stored procedures?

EDIT: I'm thinking this may have to do with a different user that's running the code with the SQL statements vs. the user that's running the SQL statements in SSMS. The user running from code has different server permissions, including limited access to tables. The SQL statement contains a view, and the user doesn't have underlying SELECT access to all the tables in that view. Would that also mean they don't have access to statistics?

Comment: As a corollary, this query runs in 16 seconds in SSMS:
DECLARE @userid AS Int = 1

Comment: I doubt it will create a different plan just due to a different userid. How sure are you that it will produce a different plan when using `sp_executesql`? You can quickly test your assumption by executing your query with `sp_executesql` using different userids in ssms.

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed parameter sniffing (you will have to see the actual plan to determine that), and you are positive you have the right indexes in place, you could update your query to use an index hint, but IMO that is not optimal way.  If you could put your query into a stored procedure, you have the ability to mark your stored proc WITH RECOMPILE, so it won't reuse the first plan. This, IMO, is a better practice than forcing index hints.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not relevant to parameter sniffing. But SET OPTIONS with SSMS and Backend.
Whenever you execute the statement from SSMS, it uses SSMS defined properties. that you can see in

**TOOLS >> OPTIONS >> Query Execution >> SQL Server >> Advanced**

You will get **SET ARITH_ABORT** option enabled in SSMS. but you didn't in your procedure.
So, add below line in your procedure and test it again.

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
```

I am very much confident about your issue, it will be resolved with this.

Comment: ... there is no stored procedure here.

Comment: then you can define this parameter in backend or add in query as well.

Comment: Jerry, thanks for your comment. SET ARITHABORT ON doesn't change the query execution time in ASP.NET code. It still times out when executed from code.